# Ubuntu 12.04 LAN connection not showing

Tags: 12.04, wubi, lan

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 with wubi along with my windows 7 system. My lan connection is working fine in windows 7 but not showing in ubuntu. I tried everything i found on this forum regarding the same issue but didn't work.

Please tell me which commands' output you need to figure out the issue ? I will post them.

Comment: that is for wireless connection. I am asking for wired connection

Comment: That wasn't clear. Try this for some ideas: http://askubuntu.com/questions/489914/ubuntu-14-04-network-problem